# Slice lines from text file

Tags: string, python-2.7, slice

I'm trying to get just the first 10 characters from multiple lines in a text file. This is what my lines look like:

```
Mon-000101,100.27242,9.608597,11.082,10.034,0.39,I,0.39,I,31.1,31.1,,double with 1355,,,,,,,,
Mon-000171,100.2923,9.52286,14.834,14.385,0.45,I,0.45,I,33.7,33.7,,,,,,,,,,
Mon-000174,100.27621,9.563802,11.605,10.134,0.95,I,1.29,I,30.8,30.8,,,,,,,,,,
Mon-000191,100.28709,9.495832,9.231,8.105,1,I,1.01,I,0,0,,on spike,,,,,,,,
```

I only want the `Mon-000101` part of the respective lines. I know I'd normally do something like this:

```
line[0:10]
```

and voila, I'd have it. But I'm trying to do this over the entire file and I'm only getting the first result.

This is the tiny code I thought might work:

```
f = raw_input("Enter the path and filename of the file: ")
f1 = open(f)
for line in f1:
    print line
```

but it's only giving me the sliced first line (correctly sliced). Is this possible to do it over all of the lines?

**New Info**: It appears my text file is just one long line which explains why I'm only getting a print-out of the first ID. I need help figuring out how to extract only the ID's (`Mon-######`).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [47]: %paste
with open('blah') as infile:
  line = []
  for char in itertools.chain.from_iterable(infile):
    if line.count(',') < 20:
      line.append(char)
    else:
      print ''.join(line[:10])
      line = [char]

## -- End pasted text --
Mon-000101
Mon-000171

Mon-00017
Mon-000191
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a bit difficult to answer this question without more information about what the actual format of your file is. You say that it may actually be one line, but does that mean that there's no real delimiter between what you thought were rows, or is it just not a newline character?

If you have some other delimiter, you could try:

```
with with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read() # read all data into one string

for line in data.split(whatever_the_real_line_delimiter_is):
    print line[:10]
```

On the other hand, if there really is no delimiter, you'll need to rely on the details of the items you want to find to identify them. A regular expression search can do that:

```
import re

with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read() # read all data into one string

for value in re.finditer(r'Mon-\d{6}', data):
    print value
```

If some of the values you want to grab don't actually start with `Mon`, you'll have to modify the pattern to match them too, but that shouldn't be too complicated if you know what you're looking for.